# Nodejs Browser-sync fails when trying to access externally

Tags: node.js, browser-sync

When I use browser sync, it works perfectly on my local machine (win 7 laptop) across all browsers, but when I try on my android mobile (which is on the same wi-fi as the laptop that I am using) using the chrome app, the page just hangs until it says that "This site can't be reached" and that it took too long to respond.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this could be happening?

(Please note: I am very new to Node and don't know a lot about it)